# How to display delete message in correct table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a function where it controls whatever happens after a file has finished uploading in its own table row. Each table row consists of a file input where the user can upload a file and then the name of the file is appended within it's own table row.

If the upload was successful then it displays a successful message, if upload was not successful then it displays a message stating there is an error. But I also have another function within the function where the user can delete a file by clicking on the "Delete" button. The only problem I have is with this line of code:

```
 $(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
```

Let's say that I have 2 table rows, and I delete a file in the first row, the message within .imagemsg should only be displayed in the first row as that was the row the deletion occured, it shouldn't display the message in the first and second row.

Another example is that if I have 4 table rows and I delete the file in the third row, then the message should be displayed in the 3rd row as that is where the deletion has occured.

So my question is what do I need to add to  `$(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);` so that the message is only displayed within the row the deletion of the file occured and not in all `.imagemsg` which is in every row?

Below is full code:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      var counter = 0;
      counter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
       });

       $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

BELOW IS HTML CODE:

```
  var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "</p><p class='listImage' align='left'></p>" +
    "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your counter variable will always be 1.  So, all your `span.imagemsg1` are the same.  This is why you get the message in every row. Set the counter outside the function to increment the counter.

I believe that will stop the behavior that you are seeing, but I would like to give a shout out to the other answers as they are giving good advice to cleaning this code up.

Frankly, you should never use unique identifier in the class. Why not use an id or a data-image-count attribute?

Comment: Good observation. It would be good to know what is calling this stepImageUpload() function. My assumptions were it was in a loop and counter meant something! ... Assumptions ...

Comment: user1364441, you can check natedavisolds theory by seeing what value this returns: $(".imagemsg" + counter).length, if it returns more than 1, then I'd say he's right on the money!

Answer (score 0):

In your html code you'll need to add a unique identifier, I would suggest using id. This way when you try to reference the element to add the error message in, it will only find one element. Currently it's looking for the first occurrence of the element with class = "imagemsg". You'll need a way to loop through each "row" and make the id's "imagemgs1", "imagemsg2", etc...Hope it helps.

Comment: That is what I tried with counter variable but it did not work. If I am going to do it how you have said to do it then how would it be coded. It would be very helpful :)

Comment: What happens if you replace "$(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);" with something like "$(this).html(data);"...Not certain that will work  for you, but since it's inside the on click event it might.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to be able to see the HTML. Also, I cannot see in your script what you do with the "result" value. At this stage, I personally don't think there is enough info to help satisfactorily you yet.

However, an issue you will undoubtedly see is with your "counter" variable. Maybe that is your problem - hard to tell without the detail I asked for above. Your jQuery.ajax call will complete at some point but the value of "counter" may not be the same as when you called the jQuery.ajax() method. This is because the "counter" variable is being declared in a different scope.

E.g. Look at the code below. It sort of demonstrates your problem with the counter variable. It may look like at the end of 5 seconds it will spit out the numbers from 1 to 10 but it won't. It will spit out the value "10" ten times.

```
var x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  x++;
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(x); }, 5000);
}
```

This problem applies to your code as well. You can fix the above by copying the variable value in to a variable of your local scope. E.g.:

```
var x = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var newScope = function() {
    x++;
    var y = x;
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(y); }, 5000);
  }();
}
```

Comment: I have added the html code at the bottom of the question so you can see the html :)

Comment: I think that Chaos wanted the html from the page the table is in.